# API Get requires Content-Type application/json;charset=UTF-8 - Issue with Http Client

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, http

I am working with an API service that requires Content-Type to be set to **application/json;charset=UTF-8**.

If I make a request *without* the charset=UTF-8 I get a **406 - Not Acceptable**.

I can make a call through Postman setting the Content-Type as required, but if I use my .Net Http Client I get the error:

> System.FormatException: 'The format of value
>   'application/json;charset=UTF-8' is invalid.'

Is there anyway I can work around this validation and force the Http Client to accept the value?

UPDATE:

Here is my latest attempt,it still throws the error.

`Body.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json;charset=UTF-8");`

UPDATE: Content-Type is indeed an invalid header. The API Developers removed it at our request.

Comment: Could you please show us the code where you set Content-Type for httpclient?

Comment: @RomanMarusyk No problem, I just added it above. Thanks!

Comment: It is not enough. Please add more code how do you make a request

Comment: Just for the record: specifying a charset for application/json is indeed meaningless. I'd report that as a bug.

Comment: @JulianReschke, that was what I was suspecting. Do you know where I can find documentation to share with the API developers to convince them remove the requirement? I assume it is violating a standard somewhere.

Comment: I have been searching around for documentation on standards to see the proper syntax for Content-Type.  I found this link which indicates that Content-Types with char sets should be valid.                
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type However, when I try to add the value: text/html; charset=utf-8 (from the link) , I get the same invalid error. System.FormatException: 'The format of value 'text/html; charset=utf-8' is invalid.'
I am definitely needing some clarification.

Comment: Last sentence in section 11 of the spec. See <https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc8259.html#ianacons>.

Answer (score 15):

Try to set the property:

```
 new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json")
        {
            CharSet = Encoding.UTF8.WebName
        };
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this one

```
HttpClient httpClient= new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

Comment: I did try this one, it returns false, indicating that it did not add the header. Also when I examine the client object I can see that it was not added to the list of headers. But thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if still relevant, but I recently ran into this same issue and was able to solve by setting the header in the following way:

```
string str = $"application/vnd.fmsstandard.com.Vehicles.v2.1+json; charset=UTF-8";

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", str);
```

Comment: Probably better do a client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear() before but other than that this should be the accepted answer. Edit: Nevermind op is  talking about the content-type not the accept header.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding double quotes around UTF-8, like this:

```
Body.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json;charset=\"UTF-8\"");
```

EDIT:

Ok, try something like this.  It's working for me locally with a WebApi I already had handy.  Notice there is a header specification for what content-type will be ACCEPTED, and then there is a header for what content-type will be SENT with the request.  For this example, both of them are JSON:

```
public static async Task<string> HttpClient(string url) 
    {
        using(HttpClient client = new HttpClient()) 
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders
                  .Accept
                  .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json")); // ACCEPT header


            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "");
            request.Content = new StringContent("{\"id\" : 1}",
                                Encoding.UTF8,  
                                "application/json"); // REQUEST header


            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();               
        }
    }
```

Comment: I got the same validation error as before. But I do appreciate the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

I only added the authentication header to it and it worked for me. `AuthToken` is either a string variable or the token itself. I left out the content type header and it just works. Below is the code; `Response` is a string that has to be serialized to a `Jobject`.

```cs
{
    String Response = null;
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(CertByPass());
    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(AuthToken);
    Response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try creating a client helper class like:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();       
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(whatever  your url);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
return client;
```

Comment: The OP says that  "a request without the charset=UTF-8 I get a 406 - Not Acceptable."